# How to use the programs installed in server through a user account?

Tags: centos, users, non-root-user

I am very new to using programs on servers
I have been alloted a user account for my Institutes's server and a storage linked to it. I don't have root permissions. 
All the programs (e.g `bedtools`,`samtools`,`bowtie2`,`tophat2`) are installed in a Softwares directory in the server and all my files are in the storage allotted. I am able to run some programs but not others. For example, I was able to run `samtools` from my directory but whenever I run a command for using `bedtools bamtofastq`, it says `-bash: command not found`. 
How to use/run the programs from my directory in storage? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

bash tries to find binaries/commands within directories specified by `$PATH` variable. See `echo $PATH` to find where bash is looking for commands.

If you want to use commands which are not in these dirs, you have to specify full path. eg. your program is stored in /opt/sw/tools, so you have to call `/opt/sw/tools/samtools`.